# In Active Record, is there an elegant way to deal with accumulating the return of a set of a set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example if I have a Automobile.  And its compatible with several 'types' of tires. 
i.e. mud tires, road tires, etc.

And then for each 'type' theres a bunch of models. i.e. goodyear, firestone, etc.

I want to be able to query an 'A.R. model' to return the full set of tire models for each tire type that it's compatible with.

So it would first query for all the types, i.e.=> snow tires and road tires, then it would loop through that set and for each of those return another set, i.e. goodyear snow tires, firestone snow tires, supertread road tires, firestone roadtires, then it would return the full set of  those.

The schema:

`Automobile=>has_many=>tire_types=>has_many=>tire_models.`

I want to query the Automobile model  and get the full set of tire_models the Automobile is compatible with.

Can I do `Automobile.tire_types.tire_models`?

Is A.R. smart enough to do all the iteration for me?

If not is there  an elegant way using A.R. features to do this or is just a basic method the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.  It involves nested has_many declarations in the model.

```
class SportSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gamedays
  has_many :games, :through => :gamedays
  has_many :results, :through => :games
```

Found in this [article](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/nested-has_many-through/).

Yet another feather in Active Record's hat.